# Calling Serverside Click event after Javascript Timer

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a page name Feedback.aspx, it contains a PopupModelExtender and on that there is a btnClose which calls server side Event to clear sessions, and reload Feedback.aspx page.

```
protected void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Timeout = 1;
        Session.RemoveAll();
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Redirect("~/frmPatientFeedback.aspx?cn=1");

    }
```

I am displaying Popup Model after a specific message and , now when it is displayed, user will have option to click btnClose which will clear sessions etc, and everything runs well.

But i want to call this btnclose function after some seconds in case user dont click the button.

so far I am able to close the modelpopup using below method:

```
<script>
var timer;
clearTimeout(timer), timer = setTimeout('HideModalPopup();', 5000);
function HideModalPopup()
        {
            $find("ModalBehaviour").hide(); 
        }
<script>
```

but how can i call btnClose server side event after .hide(), or is there any other way. once again my basic purpose for this is to clear session, and completely reload the page.

UPDATED:

HTML CODE:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Show Modal Popup" style="display:none;"/>
<!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="btnShow"CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" BehaviorID ="ModalBehaviour">
</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" style = "display:none">
<h2 id="ThankYou" class="thankYou" runat="server">شكرا!</h2>
<asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" style="display:none;" />
<asp:Button ID="modelCloseBtn" CssClass="closebtnModel" runat="server" Text="اغلق" OnClick="btnClose_Click" />
</asp:Panel>
<!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
```

Thanks

Comment: Show your html code

Comment: calling a server side function using javascript/jQuery if that is what you want then ajax is the answer. Create the function as a Webmethod and call it using ajax.

Comment: @OffirPe'er please check updated post

Comment: @Manish I tried this method, [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/769238/Call-Server-Side-Code-using-ASP-NET-AJAX-and-jQuer). But issue is we cant call Response.Redirect in webmethod.

Comment: @NisarAfridi for that what you can do is that return something from the webmethod that lets you decide that the function executed properly and based on that you can use  javascript to redirect to a different url.

Comment: @Manish yes i understand that, actually i wanted to reload the same page i-e `window.location.href = "frmpatientfeedback.aspx?cn=1";` but it dont clear sessions, cache etc on reload, and things remain same. so now i did a trick, called a Testpage, checked session at its Load and then cleared sessions, and returned back to frmpatient page.

Comment: if you reload the page then and thre it wont clear session. But if you call a webmethod and clear sessions and then based on the response reload using javascript then it will work i think. But whatever you have done is also fine as far as it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

One option is what @Manish suggested in the comment to your post: expose this functionality as a WebMethod, and call it with AJAX, or from your server side Click event handler, as needed.

Another option, which is a bit hackish, is to find the Javascript generated by ASP.NET for the button and call it from your code. But this is probably more brittle, and can easily break in the future.

Comment: I tried the method @Manish suggested, its explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/769238/Call-Server-Side-Code-using-ASP-NET-AJAX-and-jQuer) but i cannot call all things which are in my current btnClose_click event mentioned above.

Comment: @NisarAfridi you can do the redirect in the AJAX success callback, set the `document.location.href` to the new URL.

Comment: Yes i did that, but i wanted to reload the same page, and when i reload it things remain same, sessions dont get clear, cache etc. So now i moved to a test page and in that clearsessions and again back to my main  frmpatient page. I dont think so its a right way but its working for me.

Comment: `function HideModalPopup()
        {
            $find("ModalBehaviour").hide();
            window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 3000);
            window.location.href = "TestPage.aspx";
        }` in this function i am hiding the modelpopup window, then reloading current page, just to make modelwindow staty for some time, then TestPage, which will clear sessions and revertback to my main page. Just a workaround but its working.